# Why does largest eigen value used for eigen vector calcuation?

Tags: clustering, numpy, scipy, matrix

Why is the largest eigenvalue used for eigenvector calculation?
What is the significance of using a largest absolute value for the whitening of a picture?

Answer (score 1):

The largest eigenvalue of a matrix is significant because it determines the dominant behavior of the transformation and is often associated with stability and convergence properties.

Using the largest absolute value eigenvalue for the whitening of a picture is significant because it helps in decorrelating the features of the image. By using the largest absolute value eigenvalue, the whitening process ensures that the transformed image data has uncorrelated components, which can be beneficial for feature extraction and pattern recognition. It also helps in reducing the redundancy in the image data, making it more suitable for subsequent analysis and processing.